# Flex - DateField change event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using DateField as editable one in my application. And I did change event for filter function. Now I want to do the same function for each keystroke. I tried ValueCommit. But it's did nothing. My questions are:

1. Is there an event one can use when someone changes the actual value in a DateField's TextInput control?
2. How to use this textinput as a normal TextField component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keyUp event. It will be rised every time when you release pressed button in the TextField. I think this will make the trick.

```
<mx:DateField  keyUp="datefield1_keyUpHandler(event)" editable="true"/>
```